# Getting started in iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have an Android App that I have developed and I have been tasked with recreating it for the iOS platform that will work back to iOS 4.

I have purchased the Apple Developer License and I have purchased a Mac Mini and installed XCode 4.4.1 on it. I have been trying to work through some various tutorials on switching views that I have found, and I am not able to get any of them to work. Most of them talk about creating a window application or navigation application in the IDE, but apparently 4.4.1 does things in a different manner because I don't see those options in the places the tutorials show them. Then when opening referenced files there are many more entries in the files than what the tutorials show as the start. I have been fiddling with this for two days and still do not have a simple do-nothing app that just switches back and forth between views which is rather frustrating.

I looked at some of the 4.4.1 tutorials, but they have all seemed to use the storyboards which are not compatible with iOS 4.

Does anyone have any suggestions on tutorials for iOS 4 development that will work with how XCode 4.4.1 creates the project files?

Comment: Don't just follow the letter of the tutorials. Try to understand why they are telling you to do something. The exact templates provided by Xcode may have changed, but the fundamentals are the same. Also, note that you can uncheck "Use Storyboards" in the templates to not use them when starting a new application.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably start with the Stanford classes on iTunes U.  They're free and they give you a great, basic understanding of the latest and greatest iOS.

From there I would look into tutorials on  treehouse.com and www.raywenderlich.com.

Good luck.

Comment: Also, if you're in the NYC area, this is going to be awesome. http://www.meetup.com/nyc-ios-study-group/  A study group following the Stanford Courses each week.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Kirby Turner and Tom Harrington's Learning iPad Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321750403) -- it will walk you through a full app.

Answer (score 0):

This is the book I used and I found it great. [Beginning iPhone 4 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263) (Apress).

Of course this won't show you the iOS 5 way of doing things, storyboards, which cannot be used in a iOS 4 app.

Other than that I noticed on google apple docs dont always come up first when you search for something so I would add google site param so like: "UIDocumentInteractionController site:developer.apple.com"

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems to overcome and I think you should handle one at a time:

- Learn Objective-C
- Learn to get along with XCode in the current version with storyboards
- Learn to get along with XCode in the current version and still use old NIB files rather than storyboards.

So here is my suggestion

- Work through the newer tutorials with storyboards. I like the ones from Ray Wenderlich. That way you get familiar with the general concepts and learn Objective-C
- Build an app with NIB files instead of storyboard in the new XCode version and then work through the old tutorials as needed. Better if you download old full projects.

What I do not recommend is to use an old Xcode version to be found here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action