# Where to begin when creating a mobile app (iOS)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have recently starter learning iOS development, I took few tutorials online (treehouse) and used their guidance to build some simple apps.

Now I want to create a notepad, just a simple app that let you create notes...
but when I want to do it from scratch on my own I get stuck...I don't know where should I begin?...how to divide the classes I need? and how to define stuff...

could you please provide me with some basic guidance? I want to build this app myself and with help from stack overflow...no tutorials..

Thanks!! 
appreciate it

Comment: Apple provides [a very nice guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html) that will get you started. The PDF version, however, is 132 pages long. That's a good indication that this question is too broad.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970249/getting-started-in-ios

Comment: If you can't do this without a tutorial you need to do some more tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with programming basics...
OOPS concepts and stuff like that..
Then go for obj c syntax and coding basics
Then get a hold of basic applications,common objects used etc etc..

Some helpful sites

https://stackoverflow.com/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/

and ofcourse

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) [the best]

Answer (score 2):

Try these tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice they are good for starting app development in objective-c for iPhone. They also have free tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out "Paul Hegarty" videos on iOS App Development on "iTunes U" (Stanford University - CS193P Course - From Fall 2011 Onwards).